# Java: Making .txt doc into String. Performing string methods

Tags: java, methods

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
import java.io.File;

public class Book 
{     
    private String bookString;     
    private String bookTitle;     
    private String bookAuthor;

    public Book(String fileName, String title, String author)     
    {         
        readBook(fileName);         
        bookTitle = title;         
        bookAuthor = author;     
    }

    public boolean containsTitle()
    {

    }

    public int getNumOfCharacters()
    {

    }

    public int countWords(String word)
    {

    }

    public int countSentences()
    {

    }

    public String randomWord(int length)
    {

    }

    public int firstOccurrence(String word)
    {

    }

    public String getSecondSentence()
    {

    }

    public void readBook(String fileName)     
    {         
        bookString = "";         
        try         
        {             
            Scanner file = new Scanner(new File(fileName));             
            while (file.hasNextLine())             
            {                 
                String line = file.nextLine();                 
                bookString += line + "\n";             
            }             
            file.close();         
        }         
        catch (Exception e)         
        {             
            System.out.println(e);         
        }     
    } 
}
```

Here is some skeleton code that I am trying to finish. My first question is-- don't I have to store the readBook(fileName) in a variable? I tried to store it, then finish the getNumOfCharecters() method with:

bSL = bS.length() 
return bSL

I am getting an error message. "incompatible types; void cannot be converted to java.lang.String"

Thanks to anyone willing to help.

Answer (score 0):

The error you get should suggest you that the method is supposed to return a string. Change your method to :

```
public String readBook(String fileName)     
    {         
        bookString = "";         
        try         
        {             
            Scanner file = new Scanner(new File(fileName));             
            while (file.hasNextLine())             
            {                 
                String line = file.nextLine();                 
                bookString += line + "\n";             
            }             
            file.close();         
        }         
        catch (Exception e)         
        {             
            System.out.println(e);         
        } 

        return bookString;    
    }
```

then get the output into a variable like `String bS = readBook( fileName );`